# How to check if specific user have read/write/any rights on specific folder on remote machine? C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have a task to check whether does the specific user have rights on a specific folder on a remote machine and if any folder which does not have read/write/any other rights, then insert into HashSet (to avoid the duplicate value of folder path). I have written code for the which is as follow.

```cs
public static List<string> CheckFoldersPermission(List<string> folderList, string username = "")
{
    foreach (var item in lstInnerDir)
    {
        try
        {
            DirectorySecurity dSecurity = Directory.GetAccessControl(item);
            foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in dSecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)))
            {
                if (rule.IdentityReference.Value.ToLower() == username.ToLower())
                {
                    if (((rule.FileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.Read) == FileSystemRights.Read
                    || (rule.FileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.FullControl) == FileSystemRights.FullControl))
                    {
                        // do something
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // insert into HashSet //
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // catch part...
        }
    }
    return // HashSet
}
```

According to me, it should work normally and give me a list (converting from HashSet) of those folder paths on which my specific user do not have rights to read/write/anything.

Against all odds, it does nothing and those folders which does not have permitted "X" user to even read rights, my above code is not inserting that path to list.

I am now clueless that what to do to perform this task. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When debugging, step through code line by line. On each line ask yourself 'what do I expect to happen now?' Now run the code. Did it do what you expect? What was it that you expected it to do? What did it do instead? **Share that information with us (i.e. what line it was on - what you expected it to do - what it did instead)**.

Comment: Make sure you are passing the username in the correct format. I can't remember if it should include the user's domain or not, but should be a simple test while stepping through the code.

Comment: @mjwills Thank you for guidance. Did the same and found it that the issue was in other code. thank you again

Comment: You are welcome. Honestly, if you apply the advice above it will serve you well. It is one of the surprisingly useful skills for a software developer.

Comment: Indeed it is, and I forgot this, I just had in my mind that I need to complete this task by any how so.